# Hide secure Endpoints from Swagger UI but keep them in swagger.json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have some secure endpoints that I want to hide from the swagger UI but I would like to keep them in the swagger.json so that client generation and the rest can be achieved on my API.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using C#.
If that is the case, use the **[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]** attribute on the endpoints that you want to hide from the Swagger UI.

As usual configure swagger in the startup.cs file. I guess you don't need a sample method on how to enable swagger.

***Hiding secure endpoints from Swagger UI.***
In your controller apply **[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]** attribute on the endpoints that you want to hide.

Example

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] // This endpoint will be hidden from Swagger UI
    public IActionResult UnsecureEndpoint()
    {
        // Endpoint logic here
        return Ok("This is an unsecured endpoint.");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SecureEndpoint()
    {
        // Endpoint logic here
        return Ok("This is a secure endpoint.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this essentialy removes it from the swagger json documentation only.

Comment: No, it will actually hide the said endpoints it from the swagger UI, but keep it in your swagger.json file. I have working example of this

Comment: I am also looking for similar solution. Need to hide in UI but have it in generated json. The above attribute hides it in UI and json